# LiveUSB not detected by Dell laptop

Tags: boot, uefi, 20.04, live-usb

I created an Ubuntu 20.04 Live USB for an UEFI boot mode. The first time I had it plugged in, my PC detected the UEFI USB and I could boot into a live Ubuntu session.

However, the second time I tried...my PC no longer detected the USB. And there no longer seems to be an EFI partition on the USB.

Why is this happening and how do I fix this? The only thing that occurred between sessions was a disk check ran by Dell on my system. I don't know how my USB got ruined and I do NOT want to keep reformatting and reinstalling a live USB.

Comment: I have two Dell laptops, and they can boot from USB both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode. But sometimes I have to poweroff and wait for some second (30 seconds should be more than enough) and the USB drive will appear in the temporary boot menu when tapping the F12 hotkey. - If this does not work, please edit your original question and add some details: 1. model number of your Dell computer; 2. Tool used to create the USB boot drive. - I don't know what the Dell disk check did with your USB drive. Maybe you should check it with some other (less destructive) tool.

Comment: One possibility was the Dell disk check was for windows type OS/disks(don't take my word).  Bios also might have change setting for booting from USB(less likely).

Comment: "And there no longer seems to be an EFI partition on the USB." ¿Did you check with some disk utility? I mean ¿are you certain that the USB is ruined?

Comment: I had some *related* problem with a dell laptop. The machine detected the USB, showed the GRUB menu, but wouldn' boot the live OS. The same USB worked fine on other machines.